# $.get as document object

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am using phonegap. I had get the content of external website. And then I want to edit and filter the content of it. Maybe use GetElementByID or something else. However I don't know how to do. May someone provide solutions for me?

```
var $link = 'http://.....'+method2+word2+location2+'.....'; 
  $.get($link, function (data) {
  data = $(data).find('#mainContentArea');
});
```

Comment: In the latest version of jQuery, the return object can be queried - you don't need to do $(data).find(...) - just data.find(...).

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 Can you provide a _reference_?

Comment: @undefined a reference to the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 No, where have you read this that jQuery creates a jQuery object from AJAX returned data?

Comment: @undefined I haven't, I have experienced it recently. I upgraded to the lasest version and lots of my code broke. That was the reason.

Comment: @LiverpoolsNumber9 That sounds weird, as if you pass a jQuery object to `jQuery()`, it doesn't throw an error, I guess problem should be something else, I will test it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try something like below if you want to filer specific div content

```
$('#resultdiv').load($link+' #mainContentArea', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.'); // Callback function to do whatever you want to do
});
```

Callback Function - If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.

Comment: Can I edit the content inside #mainContentArea before putting it into #resultdiv?How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexer` with zero index to convert `jQuery` object to `DOM` object.

```
var $link = 'http://.....'+method2+word2+location2+'.....'; 
$.get($link, function (data) {
     data = $(data).find('#mainContentArea')[0];
});
```

Comment: Can you explain further? And how can I use it to find the content that I want to change?

Comment: After change it to DOM object,can I use getelementbyID to find the div from the external website that I want?

Comment: Its better if you use jQuery object like $(data).find('#divID')

Comment: If I use indexer, then how can I filter and edit the content inside #mainContentArea? Please provide me some examples.

Comment: you can add it first to dom, $('#domElementId').append($(data).find('#mainContentArea')); elem = document.getElementById('yourelemid');

Comment: `$('#domElementId').append($(data).find('#mainContentArea')); elem = document.getElementById('yourelemid');` I can't get the element from getelementbyid. Is that something wrong? And I don't want to show the content of #mainContentArea before edit. It seems append($(data) can't do that.